# how to provide size of button in clojure?

Tags: user-interface, button, clojure, seesaw

I am new to clojure and using seesaw for my gui. i wanted to know how to give the size of a button (or any widget for that matter) in seesaw.

I already have tried

```
(seesaw/button :text "Done"
             :size [40 :by 40]
             :listen [:action done-handler])
```

And then i wrap my button in a `seesaw/left-right-split`. When i do this my button takes the entire height and width of the right side panel. How do i give it the size i want?

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at https://gist.github.com/daveray/1441520 and https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/tree/develop/examples

Answer (score 0):

try :preferred-size instead of :size

Comment: Despite being very terse and unsure of itself, this is an attempt to answer.